# select data not coming in Controller $request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

select data is not coming on POST request.
I get the error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'department' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tickets` (`name`, `description`, `ticketer_email`, **`department`**, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asd, asd, asda, **?**, 2021-02-10 19:49:19, 2021-02-10 19:49:19))

This is my code in **web.php**

```
Route::get('/ticket/create', function(Request $request) {
        $ticket = new Ticket;

        return redirect()->back()->with('ticket',$ticket);
    });
Route::put('/ticket/create', function(Request $request) {
        $ticket = new Ticket;
        $ticket->name = $request->input('name');
        $ticket->description = $request->input('description');
        $ticket->ticketer_email = $request->input('ticketer_email');
        $ticket->department = $request->input('department');
        $ticket->save();

        
        return redirect()->back()->with('ticket',$ticket)->with('status', 'Ticket Created!');
    });
```

This is my code in **ticket.blade.php** "select item"

```
            <form action="/ticket/create" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
            <input type="hidden" name="profile" value="profile">
            <!-- FORM ROW -->
            <div class="form-row split">
              <!-- FORM ITEM -->
              <div class="form-item">
                <!-- FORM INPUT -->
                <div class="form-input small active">
                  <label for="name">Your Email</label>
                  <input id="ticketer_email" type="text" class="form-control" name="ticketer_email"  autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-input small active">
                  <label for="name">Ticket Name</label>
                  <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <!-- /FORM INPUT -->
              </div>
              <!-- /FORM ITEM -->
                   @if ($errors->has('name'))
                       <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                           <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                       </span>
                   @endif

            </div>
            <!-- /FORM ROW -->

            <!-- FORM ROW -->
            <div class="form-row split">
              <!-- FORM ITEM -->
              <div class="form-item">
                <!-- FORM INPUT -->
                <div class="form-input small full">
                  <textarea id="escription" name="description" placeholder="Write a little description about ticket..."></textarea>
                </div>
                   @if ($errors->has('description'))
                       <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                           <strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong>
                       </span>
                   @endif
                <!-- /FORM INPUT -->
              </div>
              <!-- /FORM ITEM -->

              
            </div>
            <!-- /FORM ROW -->

            <!-- FORM ROW -->
            <div class="form-row split">
              <!-- FORM ITEM -->
              <div class="form-item">
                <!-- FORM SELECT -->
                <div class="form-select">
                  <label for="department">Department</label>
                  <select id="department" name="department" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
                    <option value="0" selected>Bug</option>
                    <option value="1">Question</option>
                    <option value="2">Other</option>
                  </select>
                  <!-- FORM SELECT ICON -->
                  <svg class="form-select-icon icon-small-arrow">
                    <use xlink:href="#svg-small-arrow"></use>
                  </svg>
                  
                  

                  <!-- /FORM SELECT ICON -->
                </div>
                   @if ($errors->has('department'))
                       <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                           <strong>{{ $errors->first('department') }}</strong>
                       </span>
                   @endif
                <!-- /FORM SELECT -->
              </div>
              <!-- /FORM ITEM -->
            </div>
             <!--FORM ROW -->
            <div class="form-row split">
               <!--FORM ITEM -->
              <div class="form-item">

                  <div id="ifYes" style="display: none;">
                    <label for="car">Ticket's reason</label> <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" id="car" name="department" />
                   </div>
                   <!--FORM INPUT -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="button primary" style="width: 100%" id="save_ticket" value="{{ __(' Save ') }}">
                    </div>
                   <!--/FORM INPUT -->
              </div>
               <!--/FORM ITEM -->
            </div>
             <!--/FORM ROW -->
            
          <!-- /FORM -->
        </div>
        <!-- WIDGET BOX CONTENT -->
      </div>
      <!-- /WIDGET BOX -->
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /GRID COLUMN -->
  </div>
  <!-- /GRID COLUMN -->
</div>
<!-- /GRID -->
```

This is script for **yesnocheck**

```
            function yesnoCheck(that){
            if (that.value == "2") {
                document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

Can u help me? The rest `(name, email, description)` is coming, only the department is showing *null*.

Comment: Can you include the rest of the form? Also, include the javascript, what's `yesnoCheck` doing?

Comment: Okay, wait a minute.

Comment: I edited it, anything else?

Comment: is department in the fillable property of the model?

Comment: Yes, i have $request->input('department')

Comment: Oooo no, i have no fillable in the model

Comment: Add `var_dump($request->input());` before you `save()`, what's the output? To verify it's not coming through

Comment: Ahhh, ok, so you can skip my last comment. It's probably coming through `$_POST` but can't be set cause it's not in `$fillable`

Comment: Yes, i will add $fillable... than you so much <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is additional input field with same name `department`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" id="car" name="department" />
```

As it's second field with same name it's value is sent to controller, so it's empty string (becoming `null` by default using default Laravel `TrimStrings` middleware)

Comment: Yeees, it's workiiiing... thank youuu so much

Comment: Good find, didn't scroll enough to see that